# how to inject ravendb instance through IDatabaseFactory interface?

Tags: c#, ravendb

I have that problem that I need to call method from different project application binary
but the method accepts AService(IDatabaseFactory dbfac). I want to pass there my ravendb instance but don't know how. in my app I have:

```
 var documentStore = new Raven.Client.Document.DocumentStore { ConnectionStringName = "RavenDB" };
    documentStore.Initialize();
    var session = documentStore.OpenSession();
```

in other app I have:

```
public AService(IDatabaseFactory dbFac)
        {
            _ravenDbFactory = dbFac;
            _rdb = _ravenDbFactory.Create();
        }
```

Now how I can I pass my db session to that interface? Is it possble or do I have to implement that interface.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Raven client does not have the interface already you will need to craft it yourself. You will need to make a factory instance implementing all of the members on that interface and pass it across.